# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 's'

Tags: python

OK, so the program I have written has come up with this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'S'
```

and the line with the problem is this:

```
character = chr(int(fileText[0][i]) + shiftValue)
```

`shiftValue` is a variable that holds and integer. Can anyone give me ideas for fixing this?

Comment: Obviously your `fileText[0][i]` returns `'S'`

Comment: What does `fileText` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is `ord()`, not `int()`:

```
character = chr(ord(fileText[0][i]) + shiftValue)
```

Comment: Yes, I changed the int() to ord() and it worked after that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since the character in the file is evidently "S", I guess you actually wanted to convert it to its ascii value before shifting it. For that you use [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord), not `int()`.